# How to AUTO update MySQL after timestamp field expierd

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp

How do I automate MySQL Update or Insert upon expire timestamp?

So let say timestamp is `2013-06-30 20:10:00` and I would like to auto update MySQL DB upon passing that date and time so today after `2013-06-03 20:10:00`.

I want to update my item, but I will not have browser open with my website, so I think so I need some kind of server trigger?? How do I do that? Many thanks

I have following Query to execute every 1 second and it doesn't work:

```
CREATE EVENT e_second
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 SECOND
    DO
UPDATE online_auctions.auction_status
   SET auction_status = 'ENDED' WHERE TIMESTAMP(auction_end_date) < (select now());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use for that

1. [Mysql events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) (IMHO the best candidate)
2. cron job or Windows Task Scheduler (if you're on Windows platform)

If you go with option 1 you need to create an event

```
CREATE EVENT myevent 
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR DO 
UPDATE myschema.mytable 
   SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's `ON` you should see a process "Daemon" by user "event_scheduler". Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled. More on configuring event scheduler [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

If you want to see events that you've in your schema

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```

**UPDATE** Your update statement should look like

```
UPDATE online_auctions 
   SET auction_status = 'ENDED' 
 WHERE auction_end_date < NOW();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7960a/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you, but How do I execute it? Let say this: CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;

Comment: just like a normal MySQL Query ? please advice

Comment: MySql event scheduler will execute it for you at the time or time intervals that you specify when you create your event

Comment: Cool, but where do I get this scheduler??

Comment: It comes with MySql. [Event support was added in MySQL 5.1.6.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Comment: Can I access it via PhpMyAdmin ?

Comment: this code doesn't work: CREATE EVENT e_second
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 SECOND
    DO
UPDATE online_auctions.auction_status
   SET auction_status = 'ENDED' WHERE TIMESTAMP(auction_end_date) < (select now());

Comment: it's not executing every 1 second? I have scheduler enabled: db469163976 e_second dbo469163976@% SYSTEM RECURRING NULL 1 SECOND 2013-06-30 09:47:57 NULL ENABLED 0 utf8 utf8_general_ci latin1_general_ci

Comment: It should execute every second just fine. The problem is in an update statement which I believe is incorrect. See updated answer for crude update statement and sqlfiddle example.