# Laravel automatic update on database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I created a membership system using Laravel and I would like to know how **automatically** update the "active" column when the date is expired.

My table :

```
membership(id, dateBegin, dateEnd, active)
```

when (dateEnd > NOW) active = 0

Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to AUTO update MySQL after timestamp field expierd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387802/how-to-auto-update-mysql-after-timestamp-field-expierd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your using Laravel you could make use of its Task Scheduling to accomplish this. See the [Defining Schedules](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling#defining-schedules) section of the documentation.

Based on the example given you could do something like

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

...

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    ... 

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('membership')->whereRaw('dateEnd > now()')->update(['active' => 0]);
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the above but it should work as you require.